# Find the number of ways that 2n people may be paired.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Question: Find the number of ways that 2n people may be paired.

I have figured this problem out, and I'm fairly certain that there are $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n} n!}$ ways. However, I cannot seem to work this out using generating functions.

Consider the recurrence relation for this problem. It is given by $a_{n} = (2n-1)a_{n-1}$. It is immediate by inspection that this is just $(2n-1) \cdot (2n-3) \dots 3 \cdot 1$, which agrees with my above answer.

However, this does not agree with the way I have been instructed to solve recurrence relations (other than through the use of generating functions), which is to set $a_{n} = \alpha^{n}$, and solve for $\alpha$, which gives us $a_{n} = (2n-1)^{n}$. Why did this approach not work out?

And as far as solving this using generating functions, I've worked out that $$g(x) - a_{0} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}= 2\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n-1}x^{n} - \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n}$$

This reduces to:

$$g(x)-a_{0} = 2x\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)a_{m}x^{m} - xg(x)$$

I'm having trouble re-expressing the power series with the $(m+1)$ multiplier. To this end, I would like to ask if there is a straightforward way to re-express a power series of the form 
$\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m \cdot a_{m}x^{m}$?

I know that $x\left(\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}mx^{m}$, so I figure that $x\left(\frac{d}{dx} g(x) \right)$ should do the trick, but I wasn't able to make that approach work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your people in some way. This can be done in $(2n)!$ ways. then pick the first and second, third and fourth, etc, as your pairing. Obviously switching the first and second person will not change the pairing, so you divide by $2^n.$ Reordering the pairs arbitrarily also does not change the pairing, so that gives you another $n!,$ for a final answer of $(2n)!/(2^n n!).$

If user4140 is correct, and it is generating functions you care about: the method you describe only works for recurrences with constant coefficients, which yours is not. Your method (which gives a perfectly correct answer) is fine.

Comment: @user4140 you are not the OP -- shouldn't the OP be the one objecting? And the OP just said that he could not prove it, not that he HAD to use generating functions. And thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @user4140 He says "I could not make it work out using generating functions", which is not at all the same.

Comment: Of course if someone wishes to give an Answer as to why OP's approach using recurrence relations did not work out, that would be of interest to the OP (more than likely).

Comment: @hardmath I thought I did that ...

Comment: I agree. Some older comments are gone now, and I mistakenly thought the OP had issues about two failed approaches, not just the generating function approach.

Comment: In other words, the OP gets the correct answer from solving a recurrence relation, but then makes the mistake you point out of treating the factors (2n-1) as constants, confounding the use of $n$ as a parameter and as an index, which is essentially the same mistake introduced by trying the generating function approach.

Comment: @hardmath that seems to be the correct forensic analysis :(

Comment: Nice hat BTW, I haven't figured out its *secret*...